# Refactoring nested for() to be more concise and avoid nesting loops

Tags: angularjs, json

Is there a better way of doing a nested `for()` in angular2 rather than doing something like the code below. The code below works just want to know if there's another way of doing similar thing in a more concise way.

Object that I want to iterate over to find `itemId`: --

```
this.data = {  
 "items":[  
      {  
         "id":"1234",
         "outfit":[  
            {  
               "itemId":"1002-2"
            },
            {  
               "itemId":"1002-3"
            }
         ]
      },
more objects...
   ]
}
```

`for()` iterator code: --

```
for (let item of this.data.items) {
    for (let outfitArr of item.outfit) {
      if (itemId == outfitArr.itemId) {
        this.outfitData = outfitArr;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have an array and need iterate of it you need loop but if you don't like for you can use other loops:

```
// use foreEach + find
const findFunc = (item)=>item.itemId===itemId;

this.data.items.forEach(item=>{
    let item = item.outfit.find(findFunc);
    if(item) this.outfitData = item;
});


//use foreEach
const someFunc = (item)=>{
   if(itemId == item.itemId)
        this.outfitData = outfitArr;
};

this.data.items.forEach(item=>{
    item.outfit.forEach(someFunc)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you look into using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4).

For your specific request you can use [_.find()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find)